# How to plot data in Excel with axes using logarithmic scaling?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

See the axis of this chart

[image]

As I marked the axis with red oval, the axis is flocused toward the main bounds. How can I plot such a chart?

Comment: I see the circles, but it isn't clear to me what aspect you're referring to, or what you mean by "focused" or "main bounds".  There are axis tick marks at the grid locations.

Comment: @fixer1234 Please see the grid concentration. The axis tick marks getting close to each other with closing to the main bound. e.g. for "Msupply", from 10^0 to 10^1, the axis tick marks getting close to each other with getting close to 10^1. Did you get what I mean? please feel free to ask your question.

Comment: That's just plotting on a log scale.

Comment: @fixer1234 Could you please post your answer with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the specific thing you're looking for is plotting with a log scale.  I made a simple example with some data that would be close to a straight line on a log scale, and didn't bother matching the other formatting in your example:

[image]

The two axes are similar.  My settings for the X axis are shown.  I also turned on minor grid lines on both axes.  The Excel I had handy was v2007, so the dialog window might look a little different from yours.